# Graphics problem: vertical red stripes

Tags: graphics

Symptoms: short (about one char high) vertical red stripes, a pixel wide spaced and four or five pixels apart, cover my screen. They are most visible in black areas and least in white ones. They cover the desktop but do not affect the system tray icons. They are not present if I boot up in safe mode where I have a full desktop, but at a lower resolution than my normal 1920x1080.

Hardware and drivers, etc: 
GPU: Nvidia GeForce 2 MX 400
driver nvidia-common
OS ubuntu 12.04
monitor ASUS

What I have done:
swapped GPU into another ubuntu 12.04 system where it works fine
used monitor on another system – no problem
swapped vga cable – no change

Comments: I have been running this system (hardware and software) for a number
of months with no problems. The problem appeared a couple of days ago for no apparent reason. From my tests etc, I would think that I have eliminated hardware as a factor. So, I'm guessing the problem is due to an update or virus – but I really have no idea.

Help!!!  – this id driving me bonkers; any ideas would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have almost the same problem in my some years old MaxData laptop (nVidia GeForce Go 7400). Vertical stripes, mostly red, visible especially in BIOS / text mode screen, less in higher resolutions (1024x768). There are always about 5 stripes each 8 pixels apart, then a gap, then again stripes and so on. Additionaly when in text mode about 1/3 of all symbols are randomly changed so it looks like polnish (or any other weird language). It is always 2 characters are right, two may be changed,...
Because Windows as well as Ubuntu refuse to run with nVidia drivers (xorg works with software rendering), I suppose it is a problem with the graphics card. Maybe once it became too hot, I don't know. You said you swapped the GPU, do you mean the whole card or just the processor? Cause I could also imagine the video memory is responsible for this. Anyway, after months I finally gave up researching as it works good enough to do some programming, office, internet and even videos and 2d games, so I can live with it.

Comment: ByteCommander, thanks for the response. To clarify the GPU swap comment, I moved the NVidia card into another Ubuntu 12.04 LTS system where it worked fine. When I have some time, I'm going to reinstall the 12.04 system which should fix my problem if it's either due to a virus or update. In the meantime, I'm running by booting into the recovery system and then hitting resume. Except for slightly lower resolution and ugly blobby icons, things seem to be otherwise normal.

Of course, there's always WinXP - but that's heresy (right?).

Comment: Oh, I still would love XP if it wasn't that unsecure. In my opinion the user had more rights there than today. But at my laptop, XP did only boot in rescue mode too, at 800x600x8bit(?). Do you also have these lines in your BIOS screen like me? Then it hardly can be a virus!